# SqlDataTime overflow. Must be between 1/1/1753 12:00:00 AM and 12/31/9999 11:59:59 PM. on linq query

Tags: sql, linq, c#-4.0

I am using a linq query to retrieve records from a table as given below. When I debug the code, the error was on this linq query.

```
var tscprop = (from tscproperty in session.Query<TABProperty>()
               where tscproperty.FPropertyID == PropertyID
               select tscproperty).FirstOrDefault();
```

I have some datatime column in this table that some of them are nullable type and some are not nullable.

```
                                            Nullable Type

fOpeningDate                    datetime    no
fDRStartDate                    datetime    yes
fDateAdded                      datetime    yes
fDocumentImagingStartDate       datetime    yes
fDocumentImagingEndDate         datetime    yes
fDocumentImagingLastModified    datetime    yes
```

I am not understanding how this error is occurring while retrieving the record.

Comment: You are trying to use a date before or above the range 1/1/1753 12:00:00 AM and 12/31/9999 11:59:59 PM.

Comment: What does the definition for the `TABProperty` class look like? Is this LINQ-to-Entities or LINQ-to-SQL?

Comment: Its Linq to Entities.

Comment: This error is usually a result of an unassigned DateTime, since it is a value type it is initialized with its default value of `00:00:00.0000000, January 1, 0001.`. Then casting this default value to `SqlDateTime` results in the overflow you are seeing. You either need to handle the mismatch explicitly, or change your underlying column datatype to DATETIME2. My Preference would be for the former as realistically an unassigned date should be DbNull.

Comment: @AmitKumar, how you have defined your `DateTime` fields in your Entity framework class, All the nullable `DateTime`'s should be `Nullable<DateTime>` or `DateTime?`

Comment: I have used DateTime?

Comment: If you are comparing date time values which may be null, better ignore them in your where() clause.

Comment: But I am just retrieving record with one condition only.

Comment: I have checked and find that fOpeningDate is 1/1/0001 something like that.So how can i ignore this property while retrieving records?